# Check state of buffer in Bluetooth socket

Tags: c++, linux, bluetooth, buffer, rfcomm

I created a socket to receive data from a rfcomm socket in bluetooth.

The packages if received in one piece have 10 numbers, but sometimes I receive separate parts. It depends on the frequency I choose to acquire data. For example, if I choose `1000Hz` I get all the information. I'm using a `QTimer` and as it gets a int as interval 1000 ms / 1000 Hz is equal an int, which is OK. But if the division is not an int so the    `QTimer` will round it and it does not restart the function in time to get all the package as it desynchronizes.

I use this,

```
sock = socket (AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

numb = read (sock, buf, 10);
```

If numb is equal 10 the package was OK, so I process it. If not, a part only was received. Then that part is lost.

Is there a way to only check if the buffer is full instead of reading it already? I.e. If the state if full read it, if not, leave it to the next iteration.

I'm not really an expert in this matter, but would the flag `MSG_EOR` help me? My data cames  in packages.

Should I change `read`to `recv`? `recv` gets a socket as parameter.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I worked it out my self.

Being each package `10 bytes`, I changed the `buffer` size to have the size of `frequency * 10 bytes` so it can receive a second of acquisition and so I can have the `QTimer` with an interval of one second.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to only check if the buffer is full instead of reading it already?

You can try to use *recv* with flag MSG_PEEK. With this flag *recv* works the same way but it doesn't remove the input data from the queue.

Comment: So, if the buffer isn't full it will not change it. and if it is, it will receive and read it?

Comment: No, you should make a _while loop_ to check if it is full:
    `while(numb != 10) { numb = recv(sock, buff, 10, MSG_PEEK); Sleep(500); }`
But as I can see you found a good method so far: _recv with flag MSG_WAITALL_

Comment: With flag MSG_PEEK, your input queue (buffer) won't be changed, but it sill will be copied to your buffer returning number of bytes copied.
You can read more on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve my problem is replaying the `read()` function with `recv()` and adding the flag `MSG_WAITALL`.